# What's with the foreskin?

Tags: theology, parts-of-the-body

If it's so repulsive, why did God put it on the human in the first place? Is that when, like, the devil got ahold of the source code or something? I'm thinking of becoming Jewish, and I wanted this sorted before I talked to my parents about getting mine removed.

```
Human.addForeskin() // Take that, God! ~Satan
```

Comment: This is a good question but it has some erroneous ideas about Jewish theology.  Ours is not a dualist religion.

Comment: Besides the combative tone, which is probably reparable, this question is probably a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8545/why-is-the-prepuce-chopped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The foreskin is not repulsive. Its removal is the mark of the covenant between G-d and the Jewish people. As non-Jews have no obligation to remove it (and in fact perhaps should specifically not do do) and as non-Jews are not inherently repulsive, it stands to reason that neither is the foreskin.

There are deep kabbalistic reasons for the existence of the foreskin and its removal on Jews that are perhaps not appropriate for a public forum. If you are interested in Judaism, your first step should be to talk with your local orthodox rabbi, who will no doubt impress upon you that circumcision is neither the most difficult nor most permanent change made as a result of the conversion process.

Comment: Apparently this question was closed. Thank you for your reply, yoel, although I've been given a bad taste in my mouth about the Jewish community being unreceptive to potential-Jews. Thank you for your helpful response, and I'll talk to my local Rabbi this Sunday.

Comment: @AbrahamAaronovich Several things: First: I'm sorry your first experience with the site was unpleasant, but you should recognize that the phrasing of your question comes off as a bit flippant. Second: Jews have always [attempted to actively discourage potential converts](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16917), so please don't take the unreceptiveness to your potential-Jewishness as anything personal. Third: Nonetheless, your questions, as anyone else's,  (Jew, non-Jew, potential Jew, etc..,) will always be welcome here, but please remember to be respectful. I hope to see you around!

Comment: @AbrahamAaronovich Just to clarify HodofHod's second point: discouraging converts does not mean being rude to them, just that no one is going to talk to you and try and convince you to convert; we don't do that.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ah yes, thank you for clarifying that! :D